# iOS Swift Alamofire JSON Response Returning Bool Values as `1` or `0`

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire, boolean-operations

In alamofire response I'm returning some `Bool` Values. But it return as `0` or `1` not `true` or `false`. How to make Alamofire JSON response to return it as `true` or `false`. Here is my tried code:

```
Alamofire.request(baseurl, method: .get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    let statuscode = response.response?.statusCode
    switch response.result
    {
       case .success(_):
       if ( statuscode == 200)
       {
          let JSON = response.result.value!
          // I'm having some values like `isUserRegistered` is `true` or `false`. But it return as `0` or `1`.
       }
       case .failure(let error):
           print("Request Failed With Error:\(error)")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your response ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a type cast

```
  let JSON = response.result.value! as Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

You can convert it into bool as followings :

To convert your specfic String values to Bool you can use this extension

```
extension String {
func toBool() -> Bool? {
    switch self {
    case "True", "true", "yes", "1":
        return true
    case "False", "false", "no", "0":
        return false
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
}
```

And you can use it as follows

```
var mySting = "0"
var myBool = myString.toBool()
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x11327d210) to 'NSNumber' (0x112884488).`

Comment: Not all values are bool I'm having String, Int and Array Values in that response